# php curl upload speed very slow

Tags: php, curl

I have issues with the upload speed from curl (php 5.3).
On my development environment (laptop) the upload is very fast.
But when I deploy it on the server, it is very slow.

[EDIT]:
I am using curl to post some vars to an external service.
The service then returns XML.
If I use curl from my laptop, the XML is returned very fast.
On the server however, it takes seconds before the XML is returned.
My guess this is because the request from the server to the external service is slow.
This is illustrated by the output of the curl_getinfo() function from both my laptop (fast) and server (slow)

This is from the curl_getinfo() function on my laptop:

```
[url] => http://mylaptop.com
[content_type] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 406
[request_size] => 559
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.203
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.031
[pretransfer_time] => 0.031
[size_upload] => 283
[size_download] => 15564
[speed_download] => 76669
[speed_upload] => 1394
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.172
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
```

And this from server. It makes the total time for the curl > 5 secs.

```
[url] => http://myserver.com
[content_type] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 403
[request_size] => 424
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 5.005475
[namelookup_time] => 0.014625
[connect_time] => 0.036776
[pretransfer_time] => 0.036777
[size_upload] => 164
[size_download] => 9690
[speed_download] => 1935
**[speed_upload] => 32**
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.125857
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
```

How is this possible?
I have noticed a difference in curl versions (7.19.7 on server, 7.20.0 on laptop).

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: If I download the file from the server, it is the server uploading it to me, right?

Comment: I am very confused now (and others might be as well) as to what exactly is the scenario, it might be a good idea to clarify the situation in the question a little more.

Comment: @SabeenMalik: thanks for your feedback. I put some more info in my question, and removed my comment about "testing the server upload speed" because it seemed to confuse (and is also not relevant)

Comment: I'm sorry, been here only a couple of times and didnt receive that many answers...